# Incidental increase of validation and training loss in machine learning

Tags: validation, lstm, loss

I have a question about the losses in machine learning.
I have trained a LSTM model and after some epochs, both my validation and training loss increases from 4 to 10 mae, and then decreases again but never reaches 4 mae. Why is this the case and how can I fix it? Or should I stop training when this incidental increase of loss takes place?

Thank you if anyone can help me!